TypeError dynamic is not a subtype of type JsonQuerySnapshot
Estoy consultando contenido desde firestore con un search delegate en sus métodos buildSuggestions y buildResults, el problema me surge al querer generar la lista de sugerencias y resultados respectivamente, he probado, pero realmente no sé cómo puedo generar las listas correctamente debido a que me suelta este error:
type '(dynamic) => dynamic' is not a subtype of type '(_JsonQueryDocumentSnapshot) => bool' of 'test'
en esta parte del codigo, especificamente en el .where():
              final suggestions = snapshot.data
              .where((product) => product['descripcion']
                  .toLowerCase()
                  .contains(query.toLowerCase()))
              .toList(); //lista de sugerencias en funcion de lo tecleado

actualizacion: le di tantas vueltas al asunto solo para omitir un toString(), el problema se ha arreglado

Estas usando datos dinámicos en este caso,

type '(dynamic) => dynamic' is not a subtype of type
'(_JsonQueryDocumentSnapshot) => bool' of 'test'

tratas de realizar una comparación de product['descripcion'] para revisar si contiene query.toLowerCase(), lo correcto es que conviertas a una cadena el valor de product['descripcion'], en caso de no obtener valor asigna una cadena vacía:
final suggestions = snapshot.data!.docs
  .where((QueryDocumentSnapshot doc) {
    final product = doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
    final description = product['descripcion']?.toString().toLowerCase() ?? '';
    return description.contains(query.toLowerCase()); 
  }).toList(); //lista de sugerencias en función de lo tecleado


muchas gracias me funciona para enrobustecer el codigo

he estado haciendo pruebas y puedo confirmar que tu solucion me resolvio el problema muchas gracias
